# What is the meaning of the type/o/device flags in driver_opts in the docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, persistent-volumes

I am working on a project where I have to create costum docker containers with costum volumes etc.
As I have to use some `driver_opts`, I am wondering, what the flags

```
type: XXX
o: XXX
device: XXX
```

in a docker-compose file actually mean. I see all the people using them, but the docker manuals and all the resources I found so far couldn't provide satisfying answers. I cannot even find a simple list of what arguments you could pass to all theses flags.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

From `man mount`:

```
mount [-fnrsvw] [-t fstype] [-o options] device mountpoint
```

To summarize:

```
type: AAA
o: BBB
device: CCC
```

is (more or less*) equivalent to: `mount -t AAA -o BBB CCC <docker_generated_mountpoint>`

* - there is some parsing https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/8d193d81af9cbbe800475d4bb8c529d67a6d8f14/volume/local/local_unix.go#L122

> I cannot even find a simple list of what arguments you could pass to all theses flags.

This depends on the particular driver you are using. `man mount.cifs` differs from `man mount.nfs`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From [docker-compose driver_opts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#driver_opts-1):

> driver_opts specifies a list of options as key-value pairs to pass to the driver for this volume. Those options are driver-dependent.
>
> ```
> volumes:
>   example:
>     driver_opts:
>       type: "nfs"
>       o: "addr=10.40.0.199,nolock,soft,rw"
>       device: ":/docker/example"
> ```

In fact, these opts should exactly same with the one when you use `docker run`, see [Driver-specific options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options):

```
$ docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt o=addr=192.168.1.1,rw \
    --opt device=:/path/to/dir \
    foo
```

You should in that official document find other opts for other kinds of driver like `tmpfs`, `btrfs` etc.

**tmpfs:**

```
$  docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=tmpfs \
    --opt device=tmpfs \
    --opt o=size=100m,uid=1000 \
    foo
```

**btrfs:**

```
 docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=btrfs \
    --opt device=/dev/sda2 \
    foo
```

So, these options is really different depends on the driver type you choose.